# Shouldn't I be able to downvote in Triage?

Tags: discussion, triage

When doing triage reviews, "Should Be Improved" is reserved for content or formatting issues that the community can resolve with some work. "Unsalvagable" is supposed to be for when the question, in its current form, is not useful to the site.

However there's middleground where you think that the question has a problem/s but you don't think that the question should be flagged for closure as that's a more severe action (especially to newer users that are still learning).

In those middleground cases, I will often leave a comment telling the asker what should be improved or added, but then there isn't a relevant option for me to choose with triage. I just skip it and then the question remains unsorted. If I was able to downvote it wouldn't that give me at least the opportunity to mark it as a lower quality question. And I could then reverse this if the asker responds by fixing the question.